# Load test web server through desktop application

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, desktop

I am using JMeter to load test my web application. I have already tested all actions that are performed through a web interface. However, I also need to test one case where the web server is used to provide data to the desktop application. My web server is connected to storage, where information is held and I am able to get that information through IDE or command line. Basically, code dependencies are kept there and when the build is performed through the command line, for example, those dependencies are gathered. I need to check how many users can gather those dependencies at the same time (it is not possible to do this through the web interface). Is it possible to do with JMeter (or Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JMeter** provides [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) which allows executing arbitrary programs. If you will have > 1 threads under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - the programs will be executed in multithreaded manner. JMeter will capture response times and you will able to see reports via [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) or through [Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details.

**Visual Studio** - any programming language supported by Visual Studio provides possibility to execute external processes. However in that case you will have to develop some code to kick off dependency retrieval, do it with multiple threads, record start and end times, merge the results and parse them somehow.

Comment: I always run jmeter with admin access rights (as I have some restrictions with my ordinary user ID on Windows) and all my tests are working without problems, however this one was not working in the begining. I solved the problem running jmeter as ApacheMeter.jar with my ordinary ID and it worked (that was because this particular service from web server was not set up for admin account but for my ordinary ID).